# Dorsal vs Posterior and Ventral vs Anterior

Tags: human-biology, zoology, human-anatomy, terminology, anatomy

From prior reading, I thought that Dorsal is the same as Posterior and Ventral is the same as Anterior. However, when I checked in google images for these anatomical terms for a horse (just to strengthen my concept), i found that Dorsal is not the same as Posterior and Ventral is not the same as Anterior.

How is this possible? I have checked many websites but all state that Dorsal is the same as Posterior and Ventral is the same as Anterior. Am I going wrong somewhere?

[image]

Comment: Clearly you've been reading the wrong web sites. Look where the dorsal fin is on a fish.

Comment: Yes you were wrong before. This image is correct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Short Answer

[This page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatomical_terms_of_location) on wikipedia gives a good synopsis of these concepts.

The confusion lies in the fact that **many websites on anatomy discuss/describe/define these terms in relation to humans**. However, in [quadrupeds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrupedalism) and fish (*and*  [birds](http://www.pbase.com/image/140434563)), Anterior/Posterior lies orthogonal to Ventral/Dorsal and are instead synonymous with Cranial(Rostral)/Caudal. Examining the etymologies of the 4 terms in question will demonstrate why there seems to be an inconsistency in their usage:

```
Ventral -> "belly" side
Dorsal -> "back" side
Anterior -> "before" or "toward the front"
Posterior -> "after" or coming after (opposite to) the anterior
```

Based on the body orientation of the organism (often associated with forms of locomotion), these terms can sometimes overlap (as in bipedal humans) but often lie perpendicular to each other (as in quadrupeds, fish and most birds).

- A note about quadrupedalism (as summarized on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrupedalism) [my emphasis added]):

  > Although the words *quadruped* and *tetrapod* are both derived from terms meaning "four-footed", they have distinct meanings. A tetrapod is any member of the taxonomic unit *Tetrapoda* (which is defined by descent from a specific four-limbed ancestor) whereas a quadruped actually **uses four limbs for locomotion**.

---

#### Long Answer

Think of **ventral** (Latin *venter* = "belly") as being associated with the belly side (with belly referring to "swelling" or "inflating") -- or typically the side of the organism containing the digestive and respiratory organs. **Dorsal** (from Latin *dorsum* meaning "back") refers to the body region/"side" opposite that of *ventral* (and typically called the "back").

**Anterior** (from Latin *ante* meaning "before" or "in front of") refers to the "front" of the organism (i.e., the part of the organism you'd encounter 1st or *before* other body regions). **Posterior** (from Latin, comparative of *posterus* ("following") from *post-* meaning "after") is the opposite and refers to the part of the organism encountered "after" (or opposite) the *anterior* side.

Depending on the orientation of the organism, these terms may be synonymous in some instances but be orthogonal in other instances).

[image: Comparing anatomical positional vocabulary]

Sometimes anterior/posterior would be synonymous with ventral/dorsal, as is the case in humans or other bipedal organisms.

In other instances (e.g., in quadrupeds, fish or [birds](http://www.pbase.com/image/140434563)), posterior/anterior lies relatively orthogonal to the dorsal/ventral orientation. In these cases, dorsal/ventral is instead synonymous with **superior** (from Latin *superior*, comparative of *superus* "that is above," from *super* "above") and **inferior** (from Latin *inferus* meaning "low" or "below").

- Often in these cases, anterior/posterior are instead associated with caudal/cranial (common alternatives for cranial  include cephalic or rostral).  **Caudal** (from Latin *cauda* meaning "tail") refers to the tail side of the organism (i.e., the side associated with coccygeal vertebrae or sometimes simply the side of the organism where waste is excreted). Conversely, **cranial** (Greek *kranion* = "skull") or  **cephalic** (from Latin *cephalicus*, from Greek *kephalikos*, from *kephalē* meaning "head") refer to the side of the organism containing the head. **Rostral** (referring to *rostrum* from Latin meaning "beak") is another synonym for cranial and refers to being "situated or occurring near the front end of the body, especially in the region of the nose and mouth or (in an embryo) near the hypophyseal region."

Some notes:

- This [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3533/what-does-the-suffix-erior-mean) question addresses etymology of the suffix "*-erior*."
- You can find a pretty good list of anatomical etymologies [here](http://manoa.hawaii.edu/undergrad/learning/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Word-Roots.pdf), [here](http://www.mcpt.edu.au/A103R04_02.pdf), [here](http://www.emory.edu/ANATOMY/AnatomyManual/Etymology.html), or by simply searching "[word of interest]  etymology" in Google.
- Also, this [Bio.SE post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/55903/16866) addresses anatomical terminology usage in plants and body organs.

---

More generally, a [frontal plane](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/frontal+plane) *always* divides an organism into ventral/dorsal.

[image: quadruped vs biped]

[image: quadruped vs biped 2]

Although these terms differ between shapes/orientations of organisms, using such terms for more specific body parts (e.g., heads or feet) are [not always as inconsistent](http://vanat.cvm.umn.edu/anatDirections/VetHuman.html).

- For example, anatomical positional terminology for [brains](http://homepage.smc.edu/russell_richard/Psych2/Graphics/human_brain_directions.htm) is consistent across organisms.

[image: Anatomical positions of Brain]

One final note:

This approach to anatomical positional terminology only works with [bilaterally symmetrical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_in_biology#Bilateral_symmetry) organisms. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatomical_terms_of_location) for terminology usage for other organisms.

[image: symmetries of organisms]

Comment: [tl;dr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Too_long;_didn't_read) refers to "Too long; didn't read" ... I provide a summary for those that don't want to read the whole text. This short summary at the beginning of my answer is demarcated using the common internet acronym **tl'dr** (often applied to instances in which an author introduces a short summation of a longer piece)