# Using anatomical terms for human organs and parts of plants

Tags: botany, human-anatomy, terminology, anatomy, plant-anatomy

I know how to apply anatomical directional terms (e.g., dorsal/ventral, anterior/posterior, etc.) for animals as a whole (bipeds and quadrupeds).

Recently, I've been studying plant physiology, and I came to know that the upper surface of a leaf is the ventral surface and the lower surface of the leaf is the dorsal surface. I cannot understand how these terms are applied to plants and leaves.

I've also seen anatomical directional terms being used for body organs such as the brain.

**I want to know how anatomical terms are applied for parts of plants and body organs.**

Comment: Wonderful question. Yes in biology there are various terms to indicate  directionality and frame-of-reference for a phenomenon (such as transport) or a picture (eg. a section)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, for reference, see [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/54898/dorsal-vs-posterior-and-ventral-vs-anterior/54899#54899) for a discussion about the difference in directional terms between bipeds and quadrupeds as well as a fairly complete explanation of word meanings/etymology.

- The etymological meanings of the various anatomical directional terms should help explain their usage in body organs. For example:

  ```
  Ventral -> "belly" side
  Dorsal -> "back" side
  Anterior -> "before" or "toward the front"
  Posterior -> "after" or coming after (opposite to) the anterior
  ```

**For body organs (or other body parts):**

This [SE question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/30468/16866) addresses hands and feet, while this [page](http://serendip.brynmawr.edu/bb/kinser/BrainInfo.html) from Bryn Mawr College directly demonstrates the usage of anatomical positional terms of the brain:

[image: brain anatomical positions]

> ```
> Rostral/ Anterior --->   Head or front end
> Caudal/ Posterior --->  Tail or hind end
> Dorsal  --->    Back or top side
> Ventral --->    Belly or bottom side
> ```

Anatomical positional terminology for brains is consistent across organisms. Here is another picture demonstrating anatomical positional terminology of this organ from [Santa Monica college](http://homepage.smc.edu/russell_richard/Psych2/Graphics/human_brain_directions.htm):

[image: brain anatomical positions]

---

**For plants**, see "[Plant Identification Terminology: An Illustrated Glossary](http://lib.du.ac.ir/documents/10157/60743/Plant+Identification+Terminology+Glossary.pdf)" (Harris & Harris, 2001):

> **Dorsal.** Pertaining to the back or outward surface of an organ in relation to the axis, as in the lower surface of a leaf; abaxial. Figure 407.
>
> **Ventral.** Pertaining to the front or inward surface of an organ in relation to the axis, as in the upper surface of a leaf; adaxial. Figure 1428.

[image: Ventral/Dorsal in plants]

Therefore, dorsal/ventral are determined relative to the *axis* of where the leaf connects to the stem (ie., the *axil*). Because of this, in my experience terms such as **[abaxial](http://www.shieldsgardens.com/info/Glossary.html#abaxial)** and **[adaxial](http://www.shieldsgardens.com/info/Glossary.html#adaxial)** would be preferred when referring to plants.

Comment: So, back and bottom are opposite terms. Aren't they?

Comment: @MrAP well that depends on which context you're talking about. In some instances (e.g., quadrupeds)  they are opposite and in other instances (e.g., bipedal anatomy) they are orthogonal. In plants, neither *appears* to be the case b/c from a whole plant perspective, "back" and "bottom" would be synonymous when referring to a leaf. *However*, just like when we refer to the dorsum of a human foot, using *dorsal* (i.e., "back") when referring to a leaf uses a different point of reference (POR) than the whole plant -- dorsal still means "back", but in the case of a leaf, the POR is the leaf axil.

Comment: This is why word etymology is so important. :p

Comment: So, ventral refers to the belly side and dorsal refers to the side opposite to the belly side which is always the back side but ventral may not always be the bottom side. Right?

Comment: So, overall, the trick to understanding all of this is threefold. First, understand that each of these words has etymological meaning/background -- e.g., "ventral" originated from terminology referring to the belly side and "dorsal" originated from terminology referring to the "back." The second part of these concepts is understanding that these terms are applied in different fashions (i.e., using different points of reference). Further this is not always done appropriately based on the etymological meaning of the words themselves...

Comment: Given all that, sometimes ventral/dorsal are parallel to the ground (i.e., indicating "up"/"down" relative to the ground, respectively ) and other times they are orthogonal (i.e., indicating anterior/posterior). In cases such as the hand (facing palm forward in anatomical position) when the body is supine or plant leaves (point of reference is the leaf axil), the terms ventral/dorsal *appear* to be backwards (as in dorsal is "down" not "up" relative to the ground). Again, this is because of point of reference. Regardless of changing POR, these terms retain their etymological meaning.

Comment: Again, ventral and dorsal should be avoided when talking about plants because in such cases we are extensding these terms beyond their original etymological meaning. Terms such as abaxial and adaxial are more appropriate because they literally directly refer to the plant part that is important: the leaf axil on the stem.

Answer (score 6):

Dorsal and Ventral is very much confusing term as well as very casual term (and unscientific enough... Because we cannot compare [*our ventre*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ventre) or front with plants'). Unfortunately this casual terms widely used.

I usually avoid the term "dorsal" / "ventral"  and "upper" / "lower" **since there are available and better synonym [Adaxial](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/adaxial) and [Abaxial](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/abaxial).**

[image: ADAXIAL SURFACE AND ABAXIAL SURFACE OF LEAF]

Fig-1. Adaxial and abaxial surfaces of leaf shown on the same leaf-drawing provided in another answer.

---

P.S.

**The term "dorsal" and "ventral" have another (quite opposite)  usage in case of thalloid bryophytes** such as [*Riccia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccia) and [*Anthoceros*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthoceros). and there are also use of terms "upper" and "lower" surface;  in case of those bryophyte thalli; "ventral" or front-side is the "lower" side (towards ground) ; and "dorsal" or back-side means the "upper" side.... **and that is exactly opposite of leaves' terminology**.

> example:
>   Diagram from the textbook, *College Botany , Vol-2, by Ganguly & Kar, New Central Book Agency*...
>
> [image: Riccia Surface]
>
> The diagram (its Fig. C) describes the lower (ground-touching), rhizoid-containing surface as Ventral surface.
>
> Diagram from another textbook, *Botany for degree-students- bryophyta, by B.R. Vashishta, A.K Sinha and Adarsh Kumar; S-chand publications*
>
> [image: VS through thallus]
>
> The side where "dorsal groove"  has been pointed; is its upper surface.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}\hline
\bbox[coral]{\textbf{term}} & \bbox[yellowgreen]{\textbf{usage in an angiosperm leaf}} & \bbox[yellowgreen]{\textbf{usage in thalloid bryophyte}}\\\hline
\text{VENTRAL} & \text{Upper side, Adaxial side}& \text{Lower side}\\\hline
\text{DORSAL} & \text{Lower side, Abaxial side}& \text{Upper side}\\\hline
\end{array}$$

So a *thalloid bryophyte's  "dorsal"*  or "back" (which is upward) side is not comparable to an *angiosperm leaf's "dorsal"* or "back" (which is downward) (best to say "abaxial") side.

Similarly a *thalloid bryophytes "ventral"* or "front" (which is lower or ground-touching) side is not comparable with an angiosperm leaf's  "ventral" or front" (which is upward) (better to say adaxial) side.